# I create a responsive design it work good but search field hide on focus

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I create a responsive design it's work fine till now but the problem is when the user want to type on search field the its hide when the keypad appears on smartphone 
.
is the the browser zoom In on mode keypad shown or it's other thing that i should know ?
because i am  using function fired when the user zoom in or out the page .
the function that i am using is

```
function resize(){
    optimaizeHeader();
    (function($){
        var zoomNew = window.innerWidth;
        if(zoomNew>769 ) {
            $('#head-form').show();
            $('.right-sidebar').css("display","block");
            $('.right-sidebar').css("width","24%");
            $('.blocks-content').show();
            $('.menu').show();
            $('.blocks-content').css("width","75%");
            $('.main-content').css({"padding-left":"11%","padding-right":"11%"});
        }
        if(zoomNew<769 ) {
            $('#head-form').hide();
            $('.right-sidebar').css("display","none");
            $('.blocks-content').css("width","100%");
            $('.main-content').css({"padding-left":"3%","padding-right":"3%"});
        if(zoomNew<480){
            $(".menu").hide();
        }

    }

$('.width').text(zoomNew+" px");
    })(jQuery);
}
```

the html

```
<form id="head-form" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>">
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="type to search"/>
<button class="search-btn"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

the form hide on certain mode

Answer (score 0):

simply the focus on the search field fired up the zoom inthe solution is to compare the last resolution and the current if the tow zoom is the same don't apply the function resize just add && zoomNew!=befor to the if statement to be like this :

```
    function resize(){
optimaizeHeader();
(function($){
var zoomNew = window.innerWidth;
if(zoomNew>769 && zoomNew!=befor ) {
befor=zoomNew;
$('#head-form').show();
$('.right-sidebar').css("display","block");
$('.right-sidebar').css("width","24%");
$('.blocks-content').show();
$('.menu').show();
$('.blocks-content').css("width","75%");
$('.main-content').css({"padding-left":"11%","padding-right":"11%"});
}
if(zoomNew<768 && zoomNew!=befor) {
befor=zoomNew;
$('#head-form').hide();
$('.right-sidebar').css("display","none");
$('.blocks-content').css("width","100%");
$('.main-content').css({"padding-left":"3%","padding-right":"3%"});
if(zoomNew<480 && zoomNew!=befor){
befor=zoomNew;
$(".menu").hide();
}

}
})(jQuery);
}
```

the  demo is on the link 
http://www.demos.amp47ds.com/